# Terminology: one-word Java term for instance variables?

Tags: java, jpa, terminology, javabeans, instance-variables

I'm looking for an alternativ OO/Java term of instance variables declared in a class (non-static), or more specifically in a Java class "decorated" with JPA annotations:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Departments")
@IdClass(value = DepartmentId.class)
public class Department implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "company_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer companyId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "internal_code")
    private String internalCode;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Company company;

    ...
}
```

Are they called properties? Attributes? Members? Fields? Just references? Nothing else but instance variables?

I'd like to hear a one-word term if one exists. "Instance variables" is just too long for what I'm currently doing.

Comment: I've always just used "field". That would be the term in the Java Language Specification, as well, though it is also used as an umbrella term for instance fields and class fields.

Comment: Oh, and beans often use "property", though sometimes I've seen its use restricted to certain kinds of state.

Comment: A field is a "field", and a setter/getter represents a (Java bean) "property". To describe a field *or* property you have a "member"

Comment: I'll accept "field". A field is different from a property. The latter is just a field's accessor method then (more or less). Thanks to all who answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The JLS calls them [fields](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.3). That includes both `static` and non-`static` ones, however.

So the JLS-correct term would be "non-static field".

[Member](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.2) is a general term used for fields and methods as well as classes and interfaces defined within the class. Note that constructors and initializers (both instance initializers and static initializers) are *not* members.

A property is usually used to refer to Java Bean-type properties (i.e. a getter and a setter).

Answer (score 1):

JPA's [AccessType](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/AccessType.html) annotation uses FIELD. I would thus use the term "Field".

Answer (score 1):

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/names.html#6.4.3

Fields.

Answer (score 0):

JPA connects Java and databases. So you could call them **fields** from the database perspective or **members** from the Java perspective.

Answer (score 0):

"Member" is a typical alternative to "instance". See the [Java tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Member_variable).

Answer (score 0):

- Member
- Attribute
- Field
- Property